# Querying nested hash of hashes using PostgreSQL

Tags: json, postgresql, jsonb

I have a json datatype field to store complex data. JSON data looks like this hash:

```json
{
  "0" => {
    "origin" => {},
    "diff" => {
      "type" => "type_1",
      ...
    }
  },
  "1" => {
    "origin" => {
      "type" => "type_2",
      ...
    },
    "diff" => {
      ...
    }
  },
  ...
}
```

I've tried to transform json to array to avoid these index keys, but it did not help me.

```sql
WITH data_values AS (
  SELECT id, array_to_json(array(SELECT t.v from json_each_text(data) as t(k,v))) as array_data
  FROM event_logs
)
SELECT * FROM data_values
WHERE array_data->'origin'->>'type' = 'type_3' OR array_data->'diff'->>'type' = 'type_3'
```

Also, I had an idea to use `json_object_keys` and iterate over top-level keys to find the necessary key/value pair, but I'm a newbie to PSQL and I have some problems with solving that problem.

A version of PSQL is 11, so the JSON path is not available for me.

Table definition example:

```sql
CREATE TABLE event_logs (
    id integer,
    data json,
    created_at timestamp without time zone
);

INSERT INTO event_logs (id, data)
VALUES 
  (1, '{"0": {"origin": {}, "diff": {"type": "type_1"}}, "1": {"origin": {"type": "type_1"}, "diff": {}}}'),
  (2, '{"0": {"origin": {}, "diff": {"type": "type_2"}}, "1": {"origin": {}, "diff": {"type": "type_3"}}}'),
  (3, '{"0": {"origin": {}, "diff": {"type": "type_3"}}, "1": {"origin": {"type": "type_2"}, "diff": {}}}')
```

**Important note**: there can be a different count of top-level keys.

I want to find records by the key/value pair (for example, `type = 'type_3'`). It should select records with ID 2 and 3.

Can you help me to do it right?

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: Can you post the JSON text, not a "hash" please? Also include your table definition and the query you tried.

Comment: @S-Man I want to select all records with the necessary conditions.

Comment: @Bergi updated main post.

Comment: Without the artifical index numbers and a real array, it would be easier to query: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=e75e2c5fb0a873f96248fb4d3a05293d

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Storing the objects as an array instead of an integer-indexed object is a good idea, but that doesn't let you skip this level with the `->` operators. (Only jsonpath can do that).

You will need to use the `json_each` iteration inside your `WHERE` clauses:

```
SELECT * FROM data_values
WHERE EXISTS(
  SELECT *
  FROM json_each(data)
  WHERE value->'origin'->>'type' = 'type_3'
     OR value->'diff'->>'type' = 'type_3'
);
```

(If you had used an array, `json_each` would become `json_array_elements`).

Comment: Thank you for your solution, that's what I needed.
Btw, this wasn't my decision to store data in this strange way instead of the array of hashes :)

Comment: "*Storing the objects as an array instead of an integer-indexed object is a good idea,*" - I actually try to avoid that. And in this case it would make the query easier to write if the top level JSON was an array: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=e75e2c5fb0a873f96248fb4d3a05293d - in theory that could even use a GIST index on the column then

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name That's what I'm trying to say, using an array is better.